# What does this macports error mean & how do I fix? "p5-gd is only installed for the arch 'x86_64'"

Tags: compilation, package, macports

Port command started with PID 395
Error: Cannot install p5-sql-translator for the arch(s) 'i386 x86_64' because
Error: its dependency p5-gd is only installed for the arch 'x86_64'
Error: and does not have a universal variant.
Error: Unable to execute port: architecture mismatch

Ty for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error means that one of the packages you installed, `p5-gd`, only has a 64-bit version.  Since you're trying to install `p5-sql-translator` with both 32- and 64-bit versions, it is complaining about the `p5-gd`, which it needs to install.  Go install a fat version of `p5-gd`, or install `p5-sql-translator` for 64-bit only.